# Python matplotlib.stem plot with no markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I plot a steam plot without markers (only steam lines)?. It is specially useful when plotting really long signal arrays.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can simply set the marker to be nothing:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 200)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.stem(x, y, markerfmt=" ")

plt.show()
```

In matplotlib, there are [a few ways](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) to use "nothing" as the marker, and each gives a somewhat different result.  For example, using `""` instead of `" "` will connect the ends of the stem with a line:

[image]

Also, btw, I first tried using a pixel marker, specified by `","`, but this pixel ended up not being well aligned with the stem and didn't look good.